# How does Oxygen influence band gap in Silicon Suboxides?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, quantum-interpretations, electronic-band-theory

I just started to study about *Mott’s Formalism* and as I was going through some prerequisite material for *Variable-Range Hopping Conduction* I read the following paragraph,

*" Theories on non-defective non-doped semiconductors show that the Fermi level is positioned around mid-gap to obey the condition of charge neutrality in the material. In the case of band conduction in SiO<sub>x</sub> this would lead to an increase in activation energy with increasing x, from around 0.9 eV in a-Si up to around 1.5 eV for suboxides with x ≈ 1.5. Indeed, an increase in activation energy has been observed in several studies on the conduction of different silicon suboxides. In these studies the x dependence of the (room temper- ature) resistivity of SiOx is easily explained in terms of an increased activation energy within a band conduction model. "*

***Can someone please explain how does the band gap increase when x increases in Silicon Suboxides?***

This is the [*link*](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/672/c4.pdf) to the document.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: The likely answer is that there are defect states tailing into the gap in the sub-oxide, similar to what is seen in amorphous silicon.

Comment: Could you explain? I am new to this.